# Form dosnt go to action address

Tags: html, forms

I have a problem. I have two forms in a web page that are different action but one of my form don't work.

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform"  action="./loginAction.php" method="GET" class="login-form">

                                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="form-user">Username or Email</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username or Email..." class="form-user form-control" id="form-user" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="form-pass">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" name="upass" placeholder="Password..." class="form-pass form-control" id="form-pass" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <button name="loginBtn" value="login" type="submit" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
                                    </form>
```

even in submit dosn't redirect to action page

you can see in [this url](http://makhzan.xyz/login/)

Comment: Format the code, nicely beging you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in you html code as well as javascript code. 
Its your server code which is redirecting back to the login page . As you are using get the data should be visible in the url. When the form is submited the data cleans because its redirected to the login page. SO if you provide the server code we can have a look to it

Answer (score -1):

From a  first look  i think if you want to submit data with a form you need to set method="post"

Comment: I want to set with GET, what's problem? even post method isn't work